# Azure Queue Trigger function

Tags: azure, azure-function-app, queuetrigger

How does Azure Queue triggered function app decides whether the method succeeded or not?

Answer (score 0):

When the message is read from the queue and processed by your function app then the method becomes successful.
Once the message has been read from the queue we should no longer be able to see the message in the queue.

Comment: What does "processed" mean here? What happens to the queue message if the (Python) Function fails during processing?

Answer (score 0):

Since your trigger is the Azure Queue, you can utilize the [queue error codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/queue-service-error-codes) and handle that error codes within your Azure Function app. This documentation about [Azure Queue storage output bindings for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue-output) might be helpful to you for reference in handling those codes.

And based on those codes, it's now your preference for how your function app behaves. Either return RESTful response or throw an exception if there's an error. :)

Have a good learning journey!